# ruby syntax error 'require_relative'

Tags: ruby

So when I run ruby `server.rb`, I get this error:

> server.rb:3:in `require_relative': /Users//Desktop/ruby/route.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
>   nv["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
>
> /Users//Desktop/ruby/route.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
>       from server.rb:3:in `'

Not sure exactly what is asking. maybe some of you more experienced with ruby and or programming can shed some light.

**server.rb**

```
require 'rack'
require_relative 'view'
require_relative 'route'

class App

  PAGES = %w{ /home /admin}

  def call(env)
    response_headers = {}

    ### cookies
    request_cookies = Rack::Utils.parse_cookies(env)

    # set the session identifier if one doesn't already exist
    unless request_cookies["session_key"]
      Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!(response_headers, "session_key", Time.now.to_f)
    end

    # count the number of page visits:
    # nil.to_i returns 0, so if this cookie isn't set, the count will be 0:

    count = request_cookies["session_count"].to_i
    count += 1

    Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!(response_headers, "session_count", count)

    ### routing
    route_name = Route.new(env).name

    # get the template
    pages = Pages.new(route_name, visit_count: count)

    ### return the response object
    [status, response_headers, [pages.render]]
  end
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run App.new
```

**view.rb**

```
class View
  def initialize(page, data = {})
    @data = data
    @page = page
    file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "./pages/#{page}.html.erb")
    @page = File.read(file)
  end

  def visit_count
    @data[:visit_count]
  end

  def render
    ERB.new(@page).result(binding)
  end
end
```

**route.rb**

```
class Route

  ROUTES = {
    "/home" => :home,
    "/admin" => :admin
  }

  def initialize(env)
    if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
      @name = ROUTES[env["PATH_INFO"]]
    end
  end

  def name
    @name || "404"
  end
end
```

I've been stuck on this for some time now and I still can't figure out the solution. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're missing an opening paren here: `if (env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")`

Comment: What is your Ruby version?

Comment: your right it seems I am thanks! I can't believe i missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> server.rb:3:in `require_relative': /Users//Desktop/ruby/route.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')'

The error says, that there's a syntax error on the 9th line of `route.rb` file. Let's inspect it:

```
if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
```

It's not a valid syntax, since we have only one parenthesis, but the valid ones are either:

```
if(env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
```

Or

```
if env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"
```

So the solution is either remove the parenthesis at the end of line, or add one before `env["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")`

Comment: do you know why I'm getting this error? ERROR NameError: uninitialized constant App::Pages

Comment: @digitalking you have the following line in the `server.rb`: `pages = Pages.new(route_name, visit_count: count)`, but I don't see you have `Pages` defined anywhere. Probably you wanted to specify `pages = View.new(route_name, visit_count: count)` instead?